# How do I filter columns of multiple DataFrames stored in a dictionary in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with stock data and I want to make my data sets have equal length of data when performing certain types of analysis.

**Problem**

If I a load data for *Apple* I will get daily data since 1985 but if load data for a *Natural Gas ETF* it might only go as far back as 2012. I now want to filter *Apple* to only show history going back to 2012. Also, the end date, for example some of my dataset may not be up to date as *Apple* data is ranging from 1985 to 1-20-17 and the *Natural Gas ETF* data has a range of 2012 to 12-23-16. I also want another filter that sets the max date. So now my apple data set is filtered for dates ranging between 2012 to 12-23-16. Now my datasets are equal.

**Approach**

I have a dictionary called *Stocks* which stores all of my dateframes. All the dataframes have a column named *D* which is the *Date* column.

I wrote a function that populates a dictionary with the dataframes and also takes the min and max dates for each df. I store all those min max dates in two other dictionaries *DatesMax* and *DateMin* and then take the min and the max of those two dictionaries to get the max and the min dates that will be used for the filter value on all the dataframes.

The function below works, it gets the min and max dates of multiple dataframes and returns them in a dictionary named *DatesMinMax*.

```
def MinMaxDates (FileName):

    DatesMax = {};  DatesMin = {}
    DatesMinMax = {}; stocks = {}

    with open (FileName) as file_object:
        Current_indicators = file_object.read()
        tickers = Current_indicators.split('\n')

        for i in tickers:
            a = '/' in i 
            if a == True:
                x = i.find("/")+1
                df = pd.read_csv(str( i[x:]) + '_data.csv')
                stocks[i] = df
                maxDate = max(df.D)
                minDate = min(df.D)
                DatesMax[i] = maxDate
                DatesMin[i] = minDate
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv(i + '_data.csv')
                stocks[i] = df
                maxDate = max(df.D)
                minDate = min(df.D)
                DatesMax[i] = maxDate
                DatesMin[i] = minDate

        x = min(DatesMax.values())
        y = max(DatesMin.values())

    DatesMinMax = {'MaxDate' : x, 'MinDate' : y}
    return DatesMinMax

print DatesMinMax 
# {'MinDate': '2012-02-08', 'MaxDate': '2017-01-20'}
```

**Question**

Now, I will have to run my loop on all the dataframes in the dict name *Stocks* to filter there date columns. It seems inefficient to re-loop something again, but I can't think of any other other way to apply the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you may not need to capture min and max (since `2016-12-30 < 2017-01-20`) for later filtering, but simply run a full inner join [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) across all dataframes on 'D' (*Date*) column.

Consider doing so with a chain merge which ensures equal lengths across all dataframe, and then slice this outputted master dataframe by ticker columns to build the *Stocks* dictionary. Of course, you can use the wide master dataframe for analysis:

```
with open (FileName) as file_object:
    Current_indicators = file_object.read()
    tickers = Current_indicators.split('\n')

# DATA FRAME LIST BUILD 
dfs = []
for i in tickers:
    if '/' in i:
        x = i.find("/")+1
        df = pd.read_csv(str( i[x:]) + '_data.csv')
        # PREFIX ALL NON-DATE COLS WITH TICKER PREFIX
        df.columns = [i+'_'+str(col) for col in df.columns if col!='D']             
        dfs.append(df)

    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(i + '_data.csv')
        # PREFIX ALL NON-DATE COLS WITH TICKER PREFIX
        df.columns = [i+'_'+str(col) for col in df.columns if col!='D']
        dfs.append(df)

# CHAIN MERGE (INNER JOIN) ACROSS ALL DFS
masterdf = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['D']), dfs)

# DATA FRAME DICT BUILD
stocks = {}
for i in tickers:
    # SLICE CURRENT TICKER COLUMNS
    df = masterdf[['D']+[col for col in df.columns if i in col]]
    # REMOVE TICKER PREFIXES
    df.columns = [col.replace(i+'_', '') for col in df.columns]
    stocks[i] = df
```